# Explode a string after 5 spaces and 2 new lines in a string in PHP

Tags: php, regex, extract, explode, preg-split

I am trying to explode a string strictly after it finds 2 new lines and 5 or more spaces in a string. But should not explode if it finds less than 5 spaces or 2 new lines.

So far I have tried `preg_split("/\n\n\s\s\s\s\s*/")`, but that didn't work out.

Also, can I use explode function to for this purpose?

Comment: can you please provide an example of the string that matches the condition you want

Comment: how can i insert my string here?. i dont know how to do it.

Comment: i pasted my lines here, and it removed all the spaces and new lines ...

Comment: `var_dump(preg_split("/[\r\n]{2}[\s]{5}/", $myString));`

Comment: if the suggested comment didn't solve your problem you can edit the question an insert the string as code sample

Comment: ook .. i have got another question , how can i remove a new line from the beginning of a string. I guess that's the problem due to which the string is not exploding.

Comment: @HarjeevSingh: Please add the sample text as is with the expected result, we'll edit the post. Note that `\s` matches a newline, too. Besides, if the line break is CRLF (Windows style), you need something like a `/(?<![\r\n])\R{2}\h{5,}/` regex (i.e. `preg_split('/(?<![\r\n])\R{2}\h{5,}/', $s)`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am trying to explode a string strictly after it finds 2 new lines and 5 or more spaces in a string.

If by a "new lines" you mean `\n`, decimal `10` char and by "space" you mean a regular space, you need to use

```
$chunks = preg_split('~\n{2} {5,}~', $input);
```

where `\n{2}` matches exactly 2 new line symbols (note that there may be more in front) and  `{5,}` matches 5 or more regular spaces.

A line break may be expressed with `\r`, `\n`, `\r\n`. Then, you may use an **shorthand `\R` linbreak class**:

```
$chunks = preg_split('~\R{2} {5,}~', $input);
```

If you want to match *any 5+ horizontal whitespaces*, replace the space with `\h`, `'~\R{2}\h{5,}~'`.

And finally, if you want to make sure there is no linebreak before the 2 line breaks, add a negative lookbehind at the beginning: `'~(?<![\r\n])\R{2}\h{5,}~'`.